# What is the difference between := and = in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper, colon-equals

I want to know in Oracle PL/SQL,

= can be used for Boolean comparison, can it be used for assignment as well?

While is := used for variable initialization, can it be used for assignment too?

Then, so what is the difference between the use of 2?

Thanks!

Comment: Why dont you simply try it?

Comment: := is for assignment.  Maybe read the PL/SQL documentation http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96624/02_funds.htm

Answer (score 18):

`=` is the equality comparison operator, both in PL/SQL and SQL. `:=` is the PL/SQL value assignment operator.

These are analogous to `==` and `=` in C-derived languages.

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

General declaration syntax in PL/SQL uses ':='.Look below

variable_name datatype [NOT NULL := value ];

where,
variable_name is the name of the variable.
datatype is a valid PL/SQL datatype.
NOT NULL is an optional specification on the variable.
value or DEFAULT value is also an optional specification, where you can initialize a variable.
Each variable declaration is a separate statement and must be terminated by a semicolon.

'=' is the normal operator that we use in any other language

Comment: Just a somewhat late sidenote: `=` is not universally the assignment operator in "other language". APL uses `<-`. Smalltalk, Pascal, and a host of others use `:=`. PL/I, C et ses derivees, etc, use `=`. Clojure uses `(reset!...`). Common Lisp uses `(setq...`). Also, when defining a variable in PL/SQL you can use either `:=` or `DEFAULT` to set an initial value. Ditto and likewise for procedure or function parameters.